# Obtaining the assembly equivalent code from my C/C++ code - x86 and ARM

Tags: c++, c, assembly, x86, arm

Having a C or C++ source code how i can convert those statements in x86 and ARM assembly?
And with that i mean a plain text file containing assembly written source code from my C/C++ equivalent source code.

edit:

i use GCC/CNU toolchains

Comment: Your compiler documentation should provide you with the necessary information.

Comment: Is it really ARM or ASM?

Comment: @Borgleader it's ARM, i want to do this for 2 different architectures

Comment: Oh ok, just making sure it wasn't a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need a cross compiler that can do both then just use

```
g++ -S [Plus all you other switch's and cross compile ones]
```

This will save the intermediate assembler for you

Comment: this works quite well, but how i can specify the name for the output source file ?

Comment: It should match the source file with a different extension

Comment: yes, but i can't specify a different name or output dir or extension?

Comment: for keeping things organized and not having a mess when i try to execute a script that will do this for me and having all this extra files around.

Comment: @hthy46vbs With the `-o` option.  For more information, type `man g++` into a terminal.  Or if you are stuck with Windows, Google the same thing.

Comment: Then I suggest you write a patch for gcc/g++ if you want this and submit it to them. Sometimes you just have to do things yourself

Comment: @GregInozemtsev And how will this affect the names of the temporary files g++ generates and saves?

Comment: @AdrianCornish `-S` alone won't produce temporary files, it just means "stop after assembling".  If `-save-temps` is also specified, they are named as usual: base name of the source file + extension.

Comment: @GregInozemtsev OP Did not ask for temporary files he wanted the asm temporary files - how is that wrong?

Comment: @AdrianCornish I think we are nitpicking a tiny terminology detail :)  The GCC manual says: "-o _file_  Place output in file _file_. This applies regardless to whatever sort of output is being produced, whether it be an executable file, an object file, an assembler file or preprocessed C code."  Switches like `-S` and `-E` change the kind of output the user is requesting, so I don't think of this output as temporary: it's final.  `-save-temps` on the other hand goes all the way to the final stage, but keeps all the intermediates as well.

Comment: @GregInozemtsev Fair point - I never tried it until just now - you are correct :-)